# Can an ASPX page be given an alias so that it can be accessed from two different URLs?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I need to access the same page via two different names for the page.

Example:

`CustomersDetail.aspx` needs to be accessable using the aliased name `PartnersDetail.aspx`

CustomersDetail.aspx is the real file.

Both of the following urls should map to the same page:

```
http://www.example.com/CustomersDetail.aspx    
http://www.example.com/PartnersDetail.aspx
```

Is this possible using the Web.Config? If this is possible can the page know which url it was accessed from by looking that the request uri?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205222807/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011007-1.aspx) does an excellent job of explaining ASP.NET 2.0's method of url mapping within the web.config which allows for very readable and easily maintainable url mapping.

Essentially you will want to put the following in your web.config inside of the system.web section:

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
  <add url="~/PartnersDetail.aspx" mappedUrl="~/CustomersDetail.aspx" />
</urlMappings>
```

Answer (score 3):

Depeding on the version of the .Net Framework (introduced in 3.5) you are using you could add an entry to the RouteTable.Routes collection in the Global.asax on application start:

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("DetailReRoute",
            "PartnersDetail.aspx", //Virtual Page
            "~/CustomersDetail.aspx", //Physical Page
            false, null, null);
    }
```

Comment: Going to give this a try thanks! I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: +1  I think this would work as a programmatic way to accomplished it but another user posted a web.config solution that worked better for my needs. Someone else will find this useful though, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

May be it is a bit tough, but if you won't find a clean solution and do not want to go deep into URL-rewriting why not create the second page and just put Response.Redirect (page needed - CustomersDetail.aspx - and its URL will be shown) or Server.Transfer (page needed and the URL http://www.example.com/PartnersDetail.aspx will be shown) into the Page_Load?

Comment: +1 Not really what I'm looking for but I think it would work for me though. I might wind up accept this as the answer if no better solutions come up.

Answer (score 1):

You could also put UserControls on each page.

I meant that you could create both pages, with the names you want and place the actual content inside an UserControl. After that, you put the UserControl in both pages. Whenever you want to change the content you just change in the UserControl and it will be replicated.

I know this is not the best solution, but works nice if you want aspx pages immediately.

Comment: I meant that you could create both pages, with the names you want and place the actual content inside an UserControl. After that, you put the UserControl in both pages. Whenever you want to change the content you just change in the UserControl and it will be replicated.

Comment: +1 Yes that would work but Stephen Mesa posted an answer that works better for me. Thanks!